# Relationship between lexicographic index of size k (tuple) with that of size(k-1) tuple

Tags: combinatorics, mathematical-analysis

Given a non-negative integer $n$ such that $X = \{1,2, \dots, n\}$, a combination of k-tuple and its associated index $pos_k$.

How to compute the associated lexicographic index for any subset of the given tuple of size $k-1$?

For ex: if n = 5, then the associated index of given tuple {1,2,3} = 16. 
Given that information how to compute the index for tuple {2,3} =? instead of computing $$
\binom nk-\sum_{m=0}^{k-1}\binom{n-i_{k-m}}{m+1}\;.
$$
where subset = $\{1_i, i_2, \dots, i_{k-1}\}$